# Response Initilaze in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i try this with Kotlin Android.
But it does not work because Resonse needs to be initialized.
But how can I initialize response

```
override fun funk(): Response {

   var response : Response  


   try {
      response = proceed()
   } catch (e: SomeError) {
    ....
   }

   return response
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it nullable:

```
override fun funk(): Response? {
   var response : Response? = null

   try {
      response = proceed()
   } catch (e: SomeError) {
      ....
   }

   return response
}
```

You could also condense this method:

```
override fun funk() = 
    try {
        proceed()
    } catch (e: SomeError) {
        null
    }
```